# Laravel 5.4 relationship 2 tables 3 id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I work with laravel 5.4, and I want receive information from my relations tables.

I have 3 tables in phpmyadmin

**ATHLETES**

- ID
- FIRST_NAME
- LAST_NAME

**TYPES**

- ID
- NAME
- SLUG

**ATHLETES_TYPES**

- ID
- TYPE_ID
- ATHLETE_ID

I have 3 models

**ATHLETE**

**TYPE**

**ATHLETEBYTYPE**

How do I need to make the relations models to have name and slug from my table TYPES, with my id from my table athletes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you just need 2 model file `ATHLETE` and `TYPE` and use many to many relation.and then you can use `ATHLETES_TYPES` table as pivot table.

for implement this :

**first** add this method to `ATHLETE` model file :

```
  public function types()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(TYPE::class,'ATHLETES_TYPES','ATHLETE_ID','TYPE_ID');
    }
```

secode add this method to `TYPE` model :

```
  public function athletes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ATHLETE::class,'ATHLETES_TYPES','TYPE_ID','ATHLETE_ID');
    }
```

and in last remove `ID` filed from `ATHLETES_TYPES` table.

done.

now if you have variable from `ATHLETE` type with `$ATHLETE->types` you can get types of than.

read more here :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @MSBIZ nothing . I was copy code from my project and forget change some parameter.second parameter is pivot table name.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the relationships, buddy

In App/Athlete.php

```
class Athlete extends Model
{
    public function types(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Type');
    }
}
```

In App/Type.php

```
class Type extends Model
{
    public function Athletes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Athlete');
    }
}
```